# Project Euler #2 in F#

Tags: programming-challenge, functional-programming, f#, fibonacci-sequence

[Project Euler Problem 2](https://projecteuler.net/problem=2) asks for the sum of all even Fibonacci numbers below 4 million.

My first attempt at this problem using functional programming with F#. I would've liked to use some kind of take-while function to keep generating Fibonacci numbers until they fulfilled certain conditions, but alas I could not find such a thing in F#.

```
open System

let rec fib n = match n with
                | 0 | 1 | 2 -> n
                | _ -> fib (n - 1) + fib (n - 2)

let rec nOfFibTermsUpUntil x y = if fib (y + 1) < x then nOfFibTermsUpUntil x (y + 1) else y

[for n in 0..nOfFibTermsUpUntil 4000000 0 -> fib n]
|> List.filter (fun x -> x % 2 = 0)
|> List.sum
|> printf "The sum of Fibonacci terms up until 4,000,000 is: %d"
Console.ReadKey () |> ignore
```

Answer (score 5):

I discovered an (arguably) better way of doing this in F# using `Seq.unfold` and tuples. I'll post the solution below.

```
open System

(1,1) |> Seq.unfold (fun (a, b) -> Some(a + b, (b, a + b)))
|> Seq.takeWhile (fun x -> x <= 4000000)
|> Seq.sumBy (fun x -> if x % 2 = 0 then x else 0)
|> printf "The sum of Fibonacci terms up until 4,000,000 is: %d"
Console.ReadKey () |> ignore
```

Comment: Technically, you're supposed to takeWhile x < 4000000 (not x <= 4000000) — not that it matters, since 4000000 is not a Fibonacci number.

Comment: Yeah, I think using `seq` instead of `list` is the right way here: you can't have a potentially infinite `list`, but you can do that with `seq`.

Answer (score 2):

Your base case of `fib(2) = 2` is incorrect. No variant of the Fibonacci Sequence starts with 0, 1, 2,…. You just happen to get the same answer because the problem only cares about the even-valued terms.

To take the terms under 4 million, use [`Seq.takeWhile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370332.aspx).

Comment: You're right, removing that base case will still yield the correct answer and a valid Fibonacci sequence.

Answer (score 1):

The explicit names for things here hopefully show more clearly how `unbind` works.

```
let fibonacciSeq =
    let generator state =
        let (cur, prev) = state
        let next = cur + prev
        let state' = (next, cur)
        Some (cur, state')
    let more =
        (1, 0)
        |> Seq.unfold generator
    seq {
        0
        yield! more
    }
```